# Open embedded image as a new tab in Chrome and IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, hyperlink, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to get an embedded PNG image to open in a new tab in Chrome and IE 11.

In IE 11, the tab opens but the image is not rendered.

In Chrome, the tab does not open, however, right-clicking and "Open in a New Tab" works.

```
<a href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA ..... kJggg==" width="40%" target="_blank"> image </a>
```

I'm hoping someone has an idea what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This occurs because browsers block top-frame navigations to data URLs. For more info, check [Intent to Deprecate and Remove: Top-frame navigations to data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B1-25%5D).

As rule, to bypass this you have several options:

- Save images to the server and serve them via usual scheme (http, https, ftp).
- Open new tab using `window.open()` and write markup `<img src="data:...">`.
- Force browsers to download the image by adding the `download` attribute to the link.

Comment: Thanks Victor. This helps a lot.